# AWS CodeDeploy with Bamboo

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bamboo, aws-code-deploy

we develop a NodeJS application and we want to launch them in the Amazon Cloud.
We integrated „Bamboo“ in our other Atlassian applications. Bamboo transfer the build files to the S3 Bucket from Amazon.
The problem is: how I can move and start the Application from the S3 to the EC2 instances?


You can find my appspec.yml in the attachments and in my build directory are following files:
**- client**                         *|  files like index.html etc*
**- server**                         *| files like the server.js and socketio.js*
**- appspec.yml**
**- readme**



Have anyone an idea? I hope it contains all important informations you need.


Thank you :D



**Attachments**

```html
version: 1.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /
```

Comment: Are you using Bamboo Server or Bamboo Cloud (formerly Bamboo OnDemand? Further, how do you currently 'transfer the build files to the S3 Bucket from Amazon', i.e. with which task or tool?

Comment: @SteffenOpel We use the self-hosted version and Bamboo has a task named "AWS CodeDeploy", there you can enter your credentials, bucket details and codedeploy application/group.

Comment: I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32216170/45773) after realizing that you seem to be missing some crucial parts in your `appspec.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

I just realized that your `appspec.yml` seems to lack a crucial part for the deployment of a Node.js application (and most others for that matter), namely the `hooks` section. As outlined in [AWS CodeDeploy Application Specification Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/writing-app-spec.html), *the AppSpec file is used to manage each deployment as a series of deployment lifecycle events*:

> - During the deployment steps, the AWS CodeDeploy Agent will look up the current event's name in the AppSpec file's hooks section. [...] If
>     the event is found in the hooks section, the AWS CodeDeploy Agent will
>     retrieve the list of scripts to execute for the current step. [...]

See for example the provided [AppSpec file Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html#app-spec-ref-example) (purely for illustration, you'll need to craft a custom one appropriate for your app):

```
os: linux
files:
  - source: Config/config.txt
    destination: webapps/Config
  - source: source
    destination: /webapps/myApp
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: Scripts/UnzipResourceBundle.sh
    - location: Scripts/UnzipDataBundle.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/RunResourceTests.sh
      timeout: 180
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: Scripts/RunFunctionalTests.sh
      timeout: 3600
  ValidateService:
    - location: Scripts/MonitorService.sh
      timeout: 3600
      runas: codedeployuser
```

Without such an `ApplicationStart` command, AWS CodeDeploy does not have any instructions what to do with your app (remember that CodeDeploy is technology agnostic, thus needs to be advised how to start the app server for example).

---

#### Initial Answer

Section *Overview of a Deployment* within [What Is AWS CodeDeploy?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) *illustrates the flow of a typical AWS CodeDeploy deployment*:

[image]

The key aspect regarding your question is step 4:

> 4. Finally, the AWS CodeDeploy Agent on each participating instance **pulls the revision from the specified Amazon S3 bucket or GitHub
>      repository and starts deploying the contents to that instance**,
>      following the instructions in the AppSpec file that's provided. *[emphasis mine]*

That is, once you have started an [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/codedeploy/) deployment, everything should work automatically - accordingly, something seems to be configured not quite right, with the most common issue being that the deployment group does not actually contain any running instances yet. Have you verified that you can deploy to your EC2 instance from CodeDeploy via the AWS Management Console?

Comment: thank you, but the code doesnt appear at the server. I removed the hooks and want to test only the transfer, but i cant find the files on the server... theoretical, the files must be appear in the / directore, but theres nothing...

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you log into the Deployments list of AWS CodeDeploy console?

https://console.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/home?region=us-east-1#/deployments

(change the region accordingly)

Also the code will be downloaded in `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/<agent-id?>/<deployment-id>/deployment-archive`

And the logs in `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/<agent-id?>/<deployment-id>/logs/scripts.logs`

Make sure that the agent has connectivity and permissions to download the release from the S3 bucket. That means having internet connectivity and/or using a proxy in the instance (setting http_proxy so that code_deploy uses it), and setting an IAM profile in the instance with permissions to read the S3 bucket.

Check the logs of the codedeploy agent to see if it's connecting successfully or not : `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a deployment in code deploy and then deploy a new revision using the drop down arrow in code depoy and your S3 bucket URL. However it needs to be a zip/tar.gz/tar